# HttpWebResponse.Close Hangs for indefinite time

Tags: httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I am using HttpWebRequest to connect to a URL.  This url keeps the connection open so that it can pump the data to the client over the internet.  A custom pub/sub if you will.

It is a simple GET.

The response headers I get looks something like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: close
Date: Tue, 09 Nov 2010 23:02:11 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Anyway, when I call HttpWebResponse.Close() on the client, the call hangs indefinitely.  I do get disconnected but only when the server aborts the connection.

I tried various settings on the request object and ServicePoint, etc. with little luck.

Any idea how I can close these connections from the client side without getting hung?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `.Abort()` on the `HttpWebRequest` object just prior to calling `.Close()` on the `HttpWebResponse`.